# Scala get local values from another class without instantiating the class from main

Tags: scala, oop

I have an object called Program which can only instantiate only one class, in my case val a = new A(), in it I have a local variable called localText, I want to convert it to global, I have created a variable outside the block called globalText and inside the block I assign it globalText = localText, when I do a println it shows it correctly "Hello World", I have another class called B that needs that value but I don't know how to access it because when I call it it appears with the null value and if I call the sum function what it returns is an Int. (The sum() def cannot be touched and the data comes like this from third party code) thank you very much for the help.

...

```
  class A{
    var globalText: String = _
    def sum(): Int = {
      val localText: String = "Hello World"
      globalText = localText
      println(globalText)
      val b = new B()
      3+4

    }
     println(globalText)
  }

  class B extends A{
    var globalBText = globalText
    println(globalBText)
  }




  object Program {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val a = new A()
      println(a.sum())
      }
  }
```

Output is

```
  null
  Hello World
  null
  null
  7
```

...

Comment: "*sum() def cannot be touched and the data comes like this from third party code*" - can you link that library please?

Comment: Hello, I have written this in the simplest way with the problem I am having, the third-party library is from a company and I cannot post its code, what is true is that it returns an integer and I need to obtain the value of the local variable localText from another class but without being able to instantiate it from the main object. Since I can only instantiate once and it is in class A

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*I can only instantiate once*"? Either way, you need to call `sum()` (regardless what it returns, important is the side effect it has on `A.globalText`) *before* accessing `globalText`, there's no way around that. Also you should file a bug report against that third-party library, they should expose that variable in a better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala get local variable from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72603063/scala-get-local-variable-from-another-class)

Answer (score 1):

This question [has already been answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72604952/2205089)
Please do not create duplicate posts with the same question. You can edit the previous question, if you feel like you missed something.

If you can't instantiate the `class` than this beats the whole purpose of being a `class` and you might as well model it as an `object` or create another `object`.

The idea is that a `class` must be instantiated in order for its fields to be initialized. There is no other way.

You could use an `object` so you don't have to instantiate any `class` at all, making sure that `B.globalBText` is initialized before you used it.

Here's what I mean:

```
object A {
  var globalText: String = _

  def sum(): Int = {
    globalText = "Hello World"
    3 + 4
  }
}

object B {
  var globalBText: String = {
    A.sum()
    A.globalText
  }
  println(globalBText)
}

object Program {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(B.globalBText)
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Hello World
Hello World
```

Comment: Why did you post this answer?

Comment: I thought it was not a duplicate at first. I'm still learning the hang of the duplicate thing, and I didn't want to abuse of the flag. I see now that when a question seems duplicate, I should not answer it.